# Cannot load pixiOverlay in leaflet through vue

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, vue2leaflet

My leaflet maps were rendering too slow, I found pixiOverlay an alternative for that but I just cant make it run. Any example would help.

following is my component

```html
<template>
  <div ref="mapElement" style="height: 400px;"></div>
</template>

<script>
  // import {
  //   LMap,
  //   LTileLayer
  // } from 'vue2-leaflet';
  import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
  import 'leaflet-pixi-overlay';
  import L from 'leaflet';

  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    components: {
      // LMap,
      // LTileLayer,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        // url: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        // zoom: 3,
        // center: [47.413220, -1.219482],
        // bounds: null,
        map: L.map
      };
    },
    methods: {
      draw() {
        // this.map = L.map('map', {
        //   center: [30, 30],
        //   zoom: 13,
        // });

        var loader = new PIXI.loaders.Loader();
        loader.add('marker', 'img/marker-icon.png');
        loader.load(function(loader, resources) {
          var markerTexture = resources.marker.texture;
          var markerLatLng = [51.505, -0.09];
          var marker = new PIXI.Sprite(markerTexture);
          marker.anchor.set(0.5, 1);

          var pixiContainer = new PIXI.Container();
          pixiContainer.addChild(marker);

          var firstDraw = true;
          var prevZoom;

          var pixiOverlay = L.pixiOverlay(function(utils) {
            var zoom = utils.getMap().getZoom();
            var container = utils.getContainer();
            var renderer = utils.getRenderer();
            var project = utils.latLngToLayerPoint;
            var scale = utils.getScale();

            if (firstDraw) {
              var markerCoords = project(markerLatLng);
              marker.x = markerCoords.x;
              marker.y = markerCoords.y;
            }

            if (firstDraw || prevZoom !== zoom) {
              marker.scale.set(1 / scale);
            }

            firstDraw = true;
            prevZoom = zoom;
            renderer.render(container);
          }, pixiContainer);

          pixiOverlay.addTo(this.map);
        });
      },
      zoomUpdated(zoom) {
        this.zoom = zoom;
      },
      centerUpdated(center) {
        this.center = center;
      },
      boundsUpdated(bounds) {
        this.bounds = bounds;
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      this.map = L.map(this.$refs['mapElement']).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
      }).addTo(this.map);

      this.draw();
    },
  }
</script>
```

I tried using lifecycle hooks. The error I got previously was Container not found (now solved). The error now I am getting is "cannot read property of null"

[image: Error]

**Update 1**

```
<template>
<div ref="map" style="height: 400px;">

</div>
</template>

<script>

import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
import 'leaflet-pixi-overlay';
import L from 'leaflet';

export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    
    data() {
        return {
            
            map: L.map
        };
    },
    methods: {
        draw() {
            let loader = new PIXI.Loader()
            loader.add('marker', 'https://pixijs.io/examples/examples/assets/bunny.png')
            loader.load((loader, resources) => {
                let markerTexture = resources.marker.texture
                let markerLatLng = [51.505, -0.09]
                let marker = new PIXI.Sprite(markerTexture)
                marker.anchor.set(0.5, 1)

                let pixiContainer = new PIXI.Container()
                pixiContainer.addChild(marker)

                let firstDraw = true
                let prevZoom

                let pixiOverlay = L.pixiOverlay(utils => {
                    let zoom = utils.getMap().getZoom()
                    let container = utils.getContainer()
                    let renderer = utils.getRenderer()
                    let project = utils.latLngToLayerPoint
                    let scale = utils.getScale()

                    if (firstDraw) {
                        let markerCoords = project(markerLatLng)
                        marker.x = markerCoords.x
                        marker.y = markerCoords.y
                    }

                    if (firstDraw || prevZoom !== zoom) {
                        marker.scale.set(1 / scale)
                    }

                    firstDraw = true
                    prevZoom = zoom
                    renderer.render(container)
                }, pixiContainer)

                pixiOverlay.addTo(this.map)
            })
        },
       
        zoomUpdated(zoom) {
            this.zoom = zoom;
        },
        centerUpdated(center) {
            this.center = center;
        },
        boundsUpdated(bounds) {
            this.bounds = bounds;
        },

    },
    mounted() {
        this.map = L.map(this.$refs.map).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13)

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(this.map)

        this.draw()
    }

}
</script>
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70AKI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problematic line is:

```js
pixiOverlay.addTo(this.map);
```

Because you call `this` inside another function so that `this` is not reference to your component which means it's probably undefined or has another value.

You can solve this by using arrow function:

```js
...
  loader.load((loader, resources) => {
    ...
    var pixiOverlay = L.pixiOverlay((utils) => {
        ...
    }, pixiContainer)

    pixiOverlay.addTo(this.map);
  });
...
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls4q1b0a/)

Comment: Its working in JSFiddle but I am getting:
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:620 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: pixi_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Loader is not a constructor"

Comment: @majid Could you update your latest code? So I can see what's causing that error.

Comment: @majid Which version of pixi.js are you using? For `new PIXI.Loader()` it must be at least 5.x.

Comment: at last with your help. it is working now. my pixi.js was outdated, installed now with `npm install pixi.js`. its all good now. please if you know any good tutorial for pixi, leaflet integration do let me know. I need to make some interactive pixi graphics from geojson. Thankyou